# Passing data FromBody and FromForm in the same endpoint

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm creating a shop project in .Net Core Web API.
I have an endpoint that is responsible for creating a new product.
In the body, I pass a standard DTO model that includes "Name, Price" etc. Now I want to add the field for images to the product. These images will be saved on a server and URL in the database.
I know that images should be passed by Form, but It is possible and ok to pass data by Form and Body in one endpoint? However, should I make a separate endpoint for this operation?

Edit:
Now I have:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create([FromBody] CreatePerfumeDto dto)
        {
```

Will be ok if I change from [FromBody] to [FromForm]?

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create([FromForm] CreatePerfumeDto dto)
        {
```

Comment: Form data is passed in the request body. It is possible to pass both the images and information through "multipart form data" request.

Comment: Does my answer useful to you ?

Answer (score 2):

*FromForm and FromBody, you can only choose one of them to use.*

#### If you use `[FromBody]`, your file shoud be convert to base64 format, then your can upload it.

[image]

#### If you use `[FromForm]`, you can use `IFormFile`.

**Sample Code**

```
public class CreatePerfumeDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public IFormFile formfile { get; set; }
    public string fileName { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost("upload")]
public ActionResult CreateForm([FromForm] CreatePerfumeDto dto)
{
    var file = dto.formfile;   
    return Ok(file.FileName);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In case your class is like the code below, is there a better way?

```
public class CreatePerfumeDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public IFormFile formfile { get; set; }
    public string fileName { get; set; }
    public List<PropertyDto> MyProperty { get; set; }
}

public class PropertyDto
{
    public string PropertyX { get; set; }
    public string PropertyY { get; set; }
}
```